# Wordpress Images path are not working?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have images working on one server, but they are not working on other server, I don't know what happened..

The images in `style.css` path is set like this below on both servers. i have rechecked.

```
.category{ background:url(../images/category-icon.png); background-size:100%;}
.tabs a:hover .category{ background:url(../images/category_dark-icon.png); background-size:100%;}
```

But on server 1, it works and url becomes like this. It works.

```
http://demo.server1.com/projects/gamingcafe/wp-content/themes/gamingcafe/images/category-icon.png
```

but on server 2, it is like this. This is not working.

```
http://demo.server2.com/projects/gamingcafe/wp-content/themes/images/category-icon.png
```

My directory style is like this on both servers..

```
http://demo.server1.com/projects/gamingcafe/wp-content/themes/gamingcafe/css/

http://demo.server1.com/projects/gamingcafe/wp-content/themes/gamingcafe/images/

http://demo.server1.com/projects/gamingcafe/wp-content/themes/gamingcafe/js/

http://demo.server1.com/projects/gamingcafe/wp-content/themes/gamingcafe/less/
```

same style on server2.

Comment: Your server2 link does not seem to have "gamingcafe" as subdirectory of your themes folder

Comment: It does have, thats why all the things are coming

Comment: The urls for server 1 and server 2 are different. If each server runs the same OS, that would explain your issue. Server 2 is missing "gamingcafe" after  /wp-content/themes/

Comment: server1: `gamingcafe/wp-content/themes/gamingcafe/images/`. server2: `gamingcafe/wp-content/themes/images/` I clearly see a difference

Comment: yes its missing the gamecafe in url but gamingcafe is present there, i dont know why the url is coming up like this, the code is same on both servers.

Answer (score 1):

It most likely is related to the location in which the style.css file resides.

On **server1**, is the style.css file in the root of your theme directory, or is it in a sub-directory?

Comment: The file does exist, It is wordpress so here is my theme `gamingcafe/wp-content/gamingcafe/css` its is same on both servers.

Comment: How are you including your style.css file in your theme? Are you including it in your header.php file, or are you enqueuing it via your functions.php file?

Comment: im including it inside header.php on both servers. it works on one, but not on other, but before it was working on both.

Comment: First, I would recommend finding in the developer console the instance of the style.css file that is being generated by both sites, and absolutely confirm that they are both being delivered from the same location within your gamingcafe theme directory.

Comment: This is style.css url: `http://demo.server1.com/projects/gamingcafe/wp-content/themes/gamingcafe/css/style.css`

Comment: And what about the file path for server2?

Comment: Its same just replace server1 with server2 in the url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148549/discussion-between-ryan-and-iassassin).

Answer (score 0):

**Step one**

First, check into the header.php the file including path correct or not 
something like this way `<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`.

**Step Two**

Check your both server 1 & 2 into theme images folder  the image should be there into image folder of your theme on both servers

**Step Three**

You can try this way to call your image into CSS

```
category{ background:url("<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/category-icon.png"); background-size:100%;}
.tabs a:hover .category{ background:url("<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/category_dark-icon.png"); background-size:100%;}
```

**Step Four**

If above methods do not work then use the another way like

```
<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>
```